# How to use jquery plugins with mysql data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a product image that i want to zoom in on on mouseover. So i downloade a jquery plugin call 'jquery zoom'

The code to use on the page for the zoom is like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.mainimage').zoom({url: 'photo-big.jpg'});
});
```

EDIT******
This is the php code that shows the image on the page, in mysql i also have a big image to use on zoom.

```
$q = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT *FROM products WHERE id = $id");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
  $data = $row['image'];
  $file = substr($data, strpos($data, "/") + 1);
  echo"<article class='mainimage'>",
  "<img src='$file' class='productimage' alt='{$row['name']}' />",
  "</article>";}
```

I hope this make sense!
END EDIT****
But my image paths are stored in mysql.
How do i get them out of mysql into this bit of code?

Comment: You can insert a base64 string into an url attribute.

Comment: Normally you just embed the path in your JavaScript using PHP's `echo` function.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, i havent a clue how to do that----novice!!!

Comment: @tadman the jquery code is in the <head> and the php that gets the image is wayyyyy on down the page in the <body>. how would i do this?

Comment: jQuery makes it really easy to get data from the document itself, for example, from data attributes.

Comment: can you give me an example? or even point me somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

From the provided info, assuming you want to do all this on pageload, you would write the backend part which retrieves your info from the DB, and builds the javascript for you.

Example being:

```
// Basic DB connection handler
$dbHandler = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

// Basic data retrieval from DB
$SQL = "SELECT filename FROM files WHERE id = ?;";
$PREP = $dbHandler->prepare($SQL);
$PREP->execute(array($idToRetrieve));
$fileData = $PREP->fetch();

// Basic script output
echo "$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mainimage').zoom({url: '{$fileData['filename']}'});
});";
```

Of course, the various parts would go into their appropriate sections within your codebase. Please elaborate if this did not exactly cover your question.

** Update

You could modify your jQuery along the below lines:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mainimage').zoom({url: '$(this).attr("src")'});
});
```

Or if the zoomed image would be a different one from the small thumbnail, you would have to extend your PHP snippet something like this:

```
...
"<img src='$file' data-zoomedimage="{$row['bigimage']}" class='productimage' alt='{$row['name']}' />",     
...
```

And you would swap the `$(this).attr("src");` for `$(this).attr("data-zoomedimage");`.

Comment: I just saw your *END EDIT*, do you need assistance with that part, or is it already solved?